# Bake Maps are Coming out so patchy

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I’ve looked all over the internet trying to find the solution to my problem.

i’m trying to transfer high poly details onto a low poly mesh using the cage method

However, the final mesh, after i plug the image texture into the normal map, comes out in patches.

Any solutions? Recommendations?

I linked the file below

[Packed Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X0hlA668dcqnf5Nb63rIpkaq6Kgw57Ld?usp=drive_link)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: The Image Texture needs to be set to Non-Color, not sRGB, maybe it will fix your problem, or please pack your images and share your file

Comment: @moonboots doesnt seem to work, just turned the mesh black.

Comment: please pack the images and share your file

Comment: @moonboots i linked it above

Comment: your link asks for an authorisation

Comment: @moonboots sorry about that, it should be open now! Thanks so much for the help

Comment: For some reason that I don't understand the current material doesn't work, so I've created a brand new one, baked again (onto a 32-Bit Float image) and it works. Also before that I've selected all the faces of your high and low-poly and Ctrl E > Clear Sharp (unless you have a reason to keep sharp edges?)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for your help, is there anyway for you to put the updated file in my folder so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: I've uploaded a file called Blender_mb.blend

Comment: I've redone the whole process and it works fine now, with a 32-Bit Float image, so I'm a bit lost. Edit: it looks like it's just a problem of 32-Bit Float

Comment: @vklidu same! I seen a video on youtube, I went step by step but im still getting patches. I tried the 32-bit method and its still not working for me oddly

Comment: weird, I've tested again and it works fine with a new image that is 32-Bit Float   :/

Comment: So using my same settings that i posted, the only difference i would need to make would be checking the 32-float option?

Comment: With the current settings I've just created a new image that was 32-Bit Float, that said I'm not sure why you've sharpened the faces of your objects, maybe clear that? Ctrl E > CLear Sharp

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a problem of image settings, it needs to be *32-Bit Float*, otherwise you'll have this kind of artefacts:

[image]

Comment: Congratulation :) Works for me ... I just smell there is something more behind it. We got an issue when saved to 32bit OpenEXR and was fine when saved to 16bit. So you should probably sync bit depth in all this process like if you start with 16bit image you should save as 16bit ... iy you start with 32bit like you recommend now saving to 32bit fits ... or so ... I'm tired to think now :)

Comment: I'm not very good with all these technical things, I know it's better to have a 32-Bit Float for normal maps   :/

Answer (score 0):

*My conclusion on given question is like this ...*

---

**The simplest part :)**

Your "patches" are caused by Image texture's Color Space set to **sRGB**, the baked colours are interpreted in a wrong way...

Left-Lowpoly (Baked), Right-HighPoly
[image]

... when color space is set to **Non-Color** the issue is gone.

Left-Lowpoly (Baked), Right-HighPoly
[image]

Than saving into some format supporting 32bit dept is the best option to operate with enough colours to render smooth surface.

**Circumstances**

Your shared file is using *Image texture* > **Generated** without more info, but yesterday testing lead me to think it is a 16 bit depth only.

So when baked normals are saved into PNG format (means 16bit max) it works fine, but when you try to save this bake into OpenEXR (Full-FLoat = 32bit) it fails into "patches" again.

To get 32bit texture you have to enable **Float Buffer** under properties ...

[image]
(... or add a new *Image texture > Generated* with *32bit* enabled as suggested by moonboots in his answer.)

**Notes:**

- Part of the mishmash in the comments (when hunting the issue) probably happened due lack of data refreshing. I had to mute/unmute Image node to see render affected by changes (or under image properties press refresh icon after the path).
- Clear Sharp Edges - is probably welcomed, but not the source of the issue
- Why your render result black (you mentioned in comment) it is hard to say from given info.
- moonboots's first comment gave you correct hint to solve issue and also his posted answer is a correct solution for later save at 32bit ... so all credit is going to him ... I tried to explain why (and still I can be wrong :) )

Comment: Thank you guys very much! I tried your suggestions and it worked!